# meaning of the phrase "make it by"?

Tags: meaning

It is from this [video](https://youtu.be/8Yi77HDXjpA). It is at 6 minute and 52 second.

> And while the financial aid for college is significant, a number of stundents are still unable to **make it by** without loans.

Actually it is pretty understandable that *make it by* means to pay for education, but what confused is the use of the preposition *by* there. What is it for there? Would the sentence mean the same if the presenter left it out?

Comment: Compare with [scrape by](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/scrape_by)

Comment: I don't believe I've ever heard the expression **make it by**.  "Get by" is common, and "scrape by" as CowperKettle mentions.

Comment: **make it** alone, without **by**, has a similar meaning. "Few are able to make it without borrowing".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**by** there means "past", as in "past an obstacle".

> We have to get by that checkpoint.
>
> Move out of the way. Let me by.